# Sending mail with PHPMailer using Google's mailservers fails

Tags: php, google-api, phpmailer

I am using Google's mail servers to send emails. For email sending I am using PHPMailer. This is the snippet I am using on my example.com/contactus site:

```
        $mail             = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
        $mail-> Host      = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server

        $mail->Username   = "myprivateaddress@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
        $mail->Password   = "myprivatepassword";            // GMAIL password
        $mail->SetFrom($form_email, $form_username);
        $mail->AddAddress("support@example.com", "Example Support");
        $mail->AddReplyTo($form_email, $form_username);

        $mail->Subject    = $subject2;
        $mail->Body       = $message2;           

        $mail->CharSet     = 'UTF-8';
        $mail->Encoding    = '8bit';
        $mail->ContentType = 'text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n';
        $mail->WordWrap = 70;

        if(!$mail->Send()) {
          echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
          echo "Message sent!";
        }
```

The code sends an email to me (support@example.com) whose header is:

```
from:    user1 <myprivateaddress@gmail.com>
reply-to:    user1 <user1@gmail.com> (this is $form_email)
to:  Example Support <support@example.com>
```

The problem is when I use a different address for authentication as Username and Password the message is not sent. The error is:

```
2013-11-02 14:46:18 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 mx.google.com ESMTP u46sm21298429eep.17 - gsmtp 2013-11-02 14:46:18   CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.example.com 2013-11-02 14:46:18  SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [2a01:4f8:140:71ed::2] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250 CHUNKING 2013-11-02 14:46:18   CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 2013-11-02 14:46:18    SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 2013-11-02 14:46:18  CLIENT -> SERVER: ZGFwcHdhbGxAZ21haWwuY29t 2013-11-02 14:46:18  SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 2013-11-02 14:46:18  CLIENT -> SERVER: U3BvdGxpZ2h0OA== 2013-11-02 14:46:18  SERVER -> CLIENT: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=787 534 5.7.14 54 u46sm21298429eep.17 - gsmtp 2013-11-02 14:46:18 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=787 534 5.7.14 54 u46sm21298429eep.17 - gsmtp 2013-11-02 14:46:18  CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2013-11-02 14:46:18  SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection u46sm21298429eep.17 - gsmtp SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

I have no idea why is it working with my private gmail account that I use every day and why isn't it with other gmail accounts I have. It should be a setting in gmail maybe but which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I couldn't find out why it was not working. At the end, I changed to SendGrid. They provided an easy API and I setup the email sending in an hour with my basic skills.